# No se muestra el subcampo del grupo ACF

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin, wordpress-theme

He creado campos personalizados a través de la página Opciones de ACF del tipo `enlace`. La idea es mostrarlos en 4 tablas que se muestran haciendo uso del `repetidor` de ACF, cada tabla es individual y se usan para mostrar los mismos tipos de datos. He hecho esto mediante la creación de un grupo titulado 'Magias' con diversos campos dentro de ese grupo, en el cual 4 de esos campos son campos de `enlaces`.

Estoy tratando de mostrar los valores de ese campo (`enlace`) en la tabla pero no logro obtener el resultado correcto, ni siquiera se muestran en la tabla.

```
<?php while(have_rows('tabla-knights')): the_row(); ?>
  <td>
    <?php 
        $link = get_field('npc');
        if( $link ): 
            $link_url = $link['url'];
            $link_title = $link['title'];
            $link_target = $link['target'] ? $link['target'] : '_self';
            ?>
            <a class="button" href="<?php echo esc_url( $link_url ); ?>" target="<?php echo esc_attr( $link_target ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $link_title ); ?></a>
    <?php endif; ?>
  </td>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Dentro del grupo de campos llamado Magias:

[image: Dentro del grupo de campos llamado Magias]

Dentro del campo Tablas de Knights:

[image: Dentro del campo Tablas de Knights]

El campo NPC dentro de Tablas de Knights:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desde ya muchas gracias a quien me pueda ayudar.

### Actualización

Actualmente el campo enlace devuelve una `url`, cambié la opción de matriz a `url` de enlace.

Hice un `var_dump` del `repeater` y esto es lo que arroja:

```
Array
array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { ["npc"]=> string(19) "https://google.com/" ["ubicacion"]=> string(0) "" ["valor"]=> string(0) "" } }
```

Además e cambié a la forma apropiada de mostrar la información de los `repeater`, por lo tanto pasé de esto:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
<?php if(have_rows('tabla-knights')): ?>
      <table class="table table-sm sortable">
      <div class="col text-left p-0 my-2"><strong>Knights</strong></div>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">NPC</th>
            <th scope="col">Ubicación</th>
            <th scope="col">Valor</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php while(have_rows('tabla-knights')): the_row(); ?>
          <tr>
            <td><?php the_sub_field('npc'); ?></td>
            <td><?php the_sub_field('ubicacion'); ?></td>
            <td><?php the_sub_field('valor'); ?></td>
          </tr>  
        <?php endwhile; ?>          
        </tbody>
      </table>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

A esto:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
<?php if( have_rows('tabla-knights') ): ?>
    <!-- Loop through rows. -->
    <?php while( have_rows('tabla-knights') ) : the_row(); ?>
    <table class="table table-sm table-hover sortable">
            <div class="col text-left p-0 my-2"><strong>Knights</strong></div>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="col">NPC</th>
                  <th scope="col">Ubicación</th>
                  <th scope="col">Valor</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
        <!-- Load sub field value. -->
        <?php $sub_value = get_sub_field('npc'); ?>
        <!-- Do something... -->
              <tr>
                <td><a href=""><?php the_sub_field('npc'); ?></a></td>
                <td><a href=""><?php the_sub_field('ubicacion'); ?></td>
                <td><?php the_sub_field('valor'); ?> gps</td>
              </tr>
    <!-- End loop. -->
    <?php endwhile; ?>
            </tbody>
    </table>
<!-- No value. -->
<?php else : ?>
    <!-- Do something... -->
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Finalmente he probado y me muestra lo siguiente (lo correcto seria que dijera `Clic Aquí`):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### Acualización 2:

Ahora si bien aparece el enlace, ¿como modifico el título del mismo?:

```
<td><a href="<?php echo $sub_value; ?>">Click Aquí</a></td>
```

Con la idea de poder colocarle el título que muestra el formulario de ACF:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que he respondido varias preguntas tuyas, que bueno que sigas aprendiendo y practicando.

Primero, el campo enlace debe devolver una url, asumo no? si es así, cambia la opción de matriz de enlace por Url de enlace. Segundo, has un var dump de tu repeater y verifica que datos te muestra, aun con eso debo de decir que ACF tiene una forma propia para mostrar la información de los repeater, siendo esta:

```
<?php

// Check rows exists.
if( have_rows('repeater_field_name') ):

    // Loop through rows.
    while( have_rows('repeater_field_name') ) : the_row();

        // Load sub field value.
        $sub_value = get_sub_field('sub_field');
        // Do something...

    // End loop.
    endwhile;

// No value.
else :
    // Do something...
endif;
```

Usando `get_sub_field` como la acción para mostrar los datos de un campo que esta dentro de un repeater, verifica la documentación del plugin para más información.

Fuentes: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/repeater/

**Actualizacion**

Para mostrar el click aqui agrega lo siguiente

```
<a href="<?php echo get_sub_field('npc'); ?>">Click Aquí</a>
```

Nota: para mostrar el `field npc` no es necesario usar `get_sub_field('npc)` puede simplemente usar `echo $sub_value;` esto debido a que este valor se lo esta asignado a una variable `$sub_value = get_sub_field('npc');` o bien puede simplemente eliminar esa linea y usar `get_sub_field` para ello

```
<a href="<?php echo $sub_value; ?>">Click Aquí</a>
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu valiosa ayuda, si, me has respondido en varias ocasiones y de verdad te agradezco el tiempo y conocimiento que tomas en hacerlo, lo aprecio bastante. He revisado y he hecho lo que me has dicho, actualicé la publicación. Saludos!

Comment: He actualizado mi respuesta, si te funciono favor de marcar como aceptada

Comment: Si, me funcionó en el caso de mostrar la ruta de la página de destino, ahora como se hace para colocar el título que le he asignado a esa ruta? He actualizado la publicación.

Comment: Lastimosamente no es posible en modo de Url, para mostrar el titulo tendrías que pasarlo a matriz de nuevo y verificar en la documentación la forma de obtener esa información, al estar dentro de un repeater, tendrás que usas sub_field para que la información se muestre correctamente, siempre recuerda revisar la documentacion del plugin - https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/link/

Comment: Justamente estoy viendo eso en la documentación. Me pondré a hacer algunas pruebas. Nuevamente muchas gracias por tu valiosa ayuda y tu tiempo, de verdad que me ha servido muchísimo y me ha abierto la cabeza cada vez un poco más. Ten una excelente semana, saludos!